# Merging changes after splitting a commit without mentioning the author name

Tags: git, github

I was asked to split one big commit into multiple smaller ones in someones repository.
So I forked the repository. Did rebase and made multiple commits.

Basically at the moment I have  this on my side:

> - smaller commit 3 [Author: A]
> - smaller commit 2 [Author: A]
> - smaller commit 1 [Author: A]
> - some older commit [Author: C]

While the original repo was:

> - One huge commit [Author: B]
> - some older commit [Author: C]

What I would like do is merge the changes back to the original repo without mentioning "Author A".
That is, the original repo should look like the original author did the splitting:

> - smaller commit 3 [Author: B]
> - smaller commit 2 [Author: B]
> - smaller commit 1 [Author: B]
> - some older commit [Author: C]

What is the proper and/or the faster/easiest way to do this?

If changing authors this way is not possible, what is the cleanest way to merge the changes without cluttering the commit history too much (we are using github).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have access to the original repo as **B**, you could [cherry pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the commits made by **A**. This way you would be doing those commits as if they were being made by **B**.

**Git cherry picking**: Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one introduces, recording a new commit for each.

**EDIT:** By default cherry picking changes the **commiter** value but keeps the **author** value as the original commit. To prevent this you should use the **--no-commit** parameter and then commit the changes.

```
git cherry-pick --no-commit  86d85b4972c46c80cba49fcc8a458b803cef17f6
git commit
```

This way both **commiter** and **author** will be set to the new user.

Comment: Cherry picking seems to retain the name of original author. When cherry picking as B we still get A specified as the author.